# summation over 2 sets of positive integers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Say I have numbers $\{ a_{mn}:m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$, assume for simplicity that $a_{mn} \geq 0$. I believe it's true that
$$\sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+} a_{mn}= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn}$$
I am curious how to show this with elementary arguments.  The only 2 results I know with this flavor are

- $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{mn}$ (from Baby Rudin Ch 8) when $a_{mn} \geq 0$ as I assume

  If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges absolutely, then any rearrangement of the series converges to the same limit (at the end of Baby Rudin Ch 3).

The 2nd option seems promising right now: summing over $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is summing over a countable collection, but I don't know what the explicit rearrangement of $(\mathbb{Z}^+)^2$ is when we we sum over $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty$.

By the way, here is the motivation for my question, taken from *Real Analysis* by Yeh: 
[image] 
This is the beginning of the book so Yeh is building up the tools necessary to prove big results like Dominated Convergence and Fubini.  The latter is what I usually see for justification of the result I'm asking about, which is why I want an elementary argument because to get to Fubini in the first place it seems we need that result to build up some measure theory tools.  Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How do you define the sum on the left hand side?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure about that either.  From Yeh's proof it seems he intends to say $\{ V_{nk}:n,k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ (sorry for the change in notation, Yeh uses $\mathbb{N}$ where I use $\mathbb{Z}^+$) covers $\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$, so $\mu^*( \cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n) \leq \sum_{n,k \in \mathbb{N}} \gamma(V_{nk})= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \gamma(V_{nk})= \ldots$

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to have become: if $\{a_{mn} \, : \, m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$ is a collection of non-negative real numbers, then what does $\displaystyle\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+} a_{mn}$ mean?

You already present an interesting candidate: we know that $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{mn}$ are equal (either as non-negative real numbers or $+\infty$). Let us therefore use this common value as our definition.

> **Definition.** We define
>   $$ \sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+} a_{mn} := \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn} \quad \left(= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{mn}\right). $$

We will show that this value is indeed independent of the order of summation on $(\mathbb{Z}^+)^2$.

> **Proposition.** *We have*
>   $$ \sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+} a_{mn} = \sup \left\{ \sum_{(x,y)\in F} a_{xy} \, : \, F\subseteq (\mathbb{Z}^+)^2\ \text{non-empty and finite}\right\} $$
>   *(Note that this supremum is well-defined, either as a non-negative real number or $+\infty$.)*
>
> *Proof.* For ease of notation, let us denote the limit of the double series by $S$, and let $\mathscr F$ denote the collection of all non-empty, finite subsets of $(\mathbb{Z}^+)^2$.
>
> First we prove that $S$ is an upper bound for the collection of finite partial sums. Let $F \in \mathscr F$ be given. The $m$-th row sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn}$ is greater than or equal to the sum over all elements of $F$ that lie in the $m$-th row. By definition, $S$ is the sum of all row sums, so it is greater than or equal to $\sum_{(x,y)\in F} a_{xy}$.
>
> It remains to show that $S$ is the *least* upper bound. To that end, let $\xi < S$ be given. We show that $\xi$ is not an upper bound. (Note that $S$ may be infinite, but $\xi$ is necessarily finite.) Now we may choose some $M \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $\sum_{m=1}^M \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn} > \xi$ holds. Consequently, we can choose some small enough $\delta \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $\sum_{m=1}^M \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn} \geq \xi + M\cdot \delta$ holds.¹ Hence for sufficiently large $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, we have $\sum_{m=1}^M \sum_{n=1}^N a_{mn} > \xi$. Therefore $\xi$ is not an upper bound of the set of all finite partial sums. $$\tag*{$\Box$}$$
>
> <sub>¹: I'm saying this in a roundabout way. You typically want to choose $\delta = \frac{1}{M}\cdot \left(\sum_{m=1}^M \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn} \: - \: \xi\right)$, but this might be infinite. That's probably not a problem for the proof, but it doesn't fit my mental picture. At least now $\xi + M\cdot \delta$ is guaranteed to be finite...</sub>

It follows that the order of summation does not matter in any way. After all, we always end up taking some limit over finite sums. This is made precise in the following result.

> **Corollary.** *Let $f : \mathbb{Z}^+ \to (\mathbb{Z}^+)^2$ be any bijection, then we have*
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \big.a\big._{f(n)} = \sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+} a_{mn}. $$
>   *Proof.* Once again, let $S$ denote the limit from the right-hand side. Every finite partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^N \big.a\big._{f(n)}$ lies in the closed set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \: , \: 0 \leq x \leq S\}$, so the same holds for the limit of the series. (Once again, note that $S$ may be infinte, but that doesn't matter.) Therefore we have
>   $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \big.a\big._{f(n)} \leq \sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+} a_{mn}. $$
>   On the other hand, every finite partial sum $\sum_{(x,y)\in F} a_{xy}$ is contained in some partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^N \big.a\big._{f(n)}$ for large enough $N$, so we see that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \big.a\big._{f(n)}$ is an upper bound for the set of all finite partial sums. This shows that we also have
>   $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \big.a\big._{f(n)} \geq \sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+} a_{mn}. \tag*{$\Box$} $$

More generally:

> **Exercise.** Let $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ be given and let $f : (\mathbb{Z}^+)^k \to (\mathbb{Z}^+)^2$ be a bijection. Show that we have
>   $$ \sum_{x_1=1}^\infty \cdots \sum_{x_k=1}^\infty \big.a\big._{f(x_1,\ldots,x_k)} = \sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+} a_{mn}. $$
>   (This cannot be generalised to infinite $k$. For one thing, it is unclear how to compute an $\infty$-fold sum. More importantly, the set $(\mathbb{Z}^+)^\kappa$ is uncountable whenever $\kappa$ is infinite, so a bijection $f$ doesn't even exist, and the whole premise becomes pointless.)

---

To conclude, I will illustrate how the above results fit in with existing terminology in mathematics. The supremum from the above proposition is usually used as the definition of the sum $\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\: a_{mn}$. A vast generalisation is common in the literature, which doesn't require $a_{mn}$ to be non-negative. Some partial sums might be larger than the limit, so the supremum definition doesn't work any more. Instead, the definition is given in terms of the convergence of the [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) of finite partial sums. This definition can be generalised to arbitrary abelian [topological groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group), which provides the minimal framework for talking about infinite sums, as well as arbitrary index sets. (However, if such a series converges, then all but countably many terms must be equal to zero.) This is not just a theoretical curiosity; it is for instance needed when dealing with (uncountable) orthonormal bases in ([inseperable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space)) [Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space).